# When using multi-instance, can you launch an app automatically?

Tags: bluestacks

I see that you can pass a JSON object to bluestack to start an application automatically as soon as the instance is up from a shortcut.  However, my question is can yo do this via the multi-instance manager?  It's 3 more icons that I don't have to have and they would start quicker than if you do it individually.

Answer (score 0):

use -vmname
like HD-Runapp.exe -vmname Android_ ...
there is no (readable) table where you can find <Android_instancenumber> - InstanceName
so you will have to maintain your own table

Comment: Thanks for that.  How do you find the <Android_instancenumber> in the first place?